# Can't destroy my buildings as Engineer

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

Something changed in the game's GUI and control scheme, and now Engineer doesn't have a 5th slot item, if you disable the fast switch, where I only see 4 items now. I don't think this can be done with a GUI mod (if I had one installed in the first place). The construction tool seems to have changed to a both construction and destruction multipurpose tool, and the menu is now called "Engineering". Spy's GUI for choosing a disguise has also changed.

[image]

it used to be like this:

[image]

Before this change I was able to press 5-1 to destroy my sentry, for example. Now pressing 5 just beeps like I'm pressing 7 or 9 for a non-existent slot. I can't destroy any of my buildings!

Spy's GUI also showed which keys you need to press to change the team color of disguise, which now changed to just "Change team" text, and no visible key indicator.

Maybe it's some conversion to cursor-based selection which went wrong, idk. I just want to be able to destroy my buildings again by pressing 5-1, without having to resort to using custom configs and alias-binding "destroy" command. How can I do that?

I have tried deleting everything and resetting my configs manually, downloading old default configs, didn't help. **I also never installed any custom GUI stuff to begin with.**

If I type `version` into console, it shows this:

```
Build Label:           3943693   # Uniquely identifies each build
Network PatchVersion:  3920631   # Determines client and server compatibility
Protocol version:           24   # High level network protocol version
Server version:        3943693
Server AppID:           232250
Client version:        3920631
Client AppID:              440
```

Comment: idk why this was downvoted, I just encountered this.

Answer (score 5):

The current version of TF2 does not have this interface. You likely modified your own installation somehow. Pictures made a few minutes ago:

[image: Demolish]

[image: Build]

[image: Spy]

**Edit:**

After OP mentioning Gamepad controls, I googled a bit. According to [this resource](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Xbox_360_controls) you can enable them only via the console by executing `exec 360controller`. Trying this one does indeed get the HUD as shown by OP. You can access demolish with left trigger, and build with right trigger. Use `exec undo360controller` to get your normal HUD back.

Comment: If this isn't something I downloaded, maybe it's some kinda gamepad-oriented style of GUI.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the button 5 does nothing and the item is missing from the 5th slot and pressing 5 does nothing. I don't think it's something I can possibly do with a GUI modification.

Comment: Well, you don't accidentally enable a gamepad oriented gui, so you must know if you enabled it or not. If you did, there is probably also a way of disabling it. Deleting config files probably doesn't work, because it would download them from the cloud again anyway.

Comment: I cleared out config multiple times. I've learned that there might be settings which don't get saved in the config.cfg file and may be stored otherwise. Maybe what's causing this is there. Or maybe this is a limited update for a new interface being pushed to select players. Who knows.

Comment: "Or maybe this is a limited update for a new interface being pushed to select players." No, it's definitely not that.

Comment: I just can't explain the missing destruction tool and how the "Build" text got changed to "Engineering" any other way.

Comment: @Sumurai8 can you post what it shows when you type "version" into console?

Comment: I saw those exec360 configs before, and they don't help in my case. I restarted, enabled, restarted, disabled, yada yada, back and forth. Doesn't help. At least this isn't something I made up, that's reassuring.

Comment: Then uninstall your game completely. Do a fresh install. Disable sync with the steam cloud.

Comment: @TheEngineer - do you have an X-input device plugged in to your PC? an Xbox 360 or One controller, or a third party controller that follows the same standard? AFAIK the Xbox360 control scheme is activated automatically when it detects a compatible device plugged in